# Watir faster way to click link

Tags: watir

I'm using the following command in an .rb script to click a link for a web page that I'm developing a test plan.  It seems, however, that when this command is executed, there is a 3 second delay between initiating and the system recognizing it.  I can click the link manually and it's almost instantaneous.

b.link(:text, "Submit ITSM").click

I've added "b.speed = :fast" before my loop which contains the click above but no improvement.

Are there certain ":names" that work faster than others like ":id" or something? Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  used the following instead:

b.div(:id, "(id)").link(:class, "(class)").click